STM32F030 Not able to Connect with ST-Link
I am connecting the CLK, RST, DIO, 3.3 & GND from ST-Link to the STM32 via a jumper. When I try to connect 3.3 & GND, the ST-Link disconnects immediately. Can anyone have a look & see if there is anything wrong here?


We don't know why it happens. You only show the MCU. Is the MCU powered with external supply? Which ST-Link you have, a genuine item from ST or random clone nobody knows how it works unless you have a manual?

"the ST-Link disconnects immediately" isn't very informative... do you get an error message? do you see any signals on the SWCLK / SWDIO pins? what software are you using? have you tried "connect under reset"? is the part new or locked?

@Justme MCU is powered by the ST-Link. When I connect both 3.3 & GND wires from the ST-Link to the PCB, my computer removes the ST-Link ( there is a sound, when you plug or unplug any USB device, so in this case, it is like I have unplugged the ST-Link, and its onboard LED on the ST-Link also goes off). This is a Chinese clone which has worked well with all my PCBs till date but I am going to try the genuine ST-Link which I have and update.

@JSNerd01 Only the clones have 3.3V output. Some but not all official models have 3.3V output as well but in practice you need to power your board yourself. Either your board draws too much current or has a short circuit. In which case you should not be plugging it to power it from your PC. Is there anything else that gets powered than the STM32?

@Justme in this case, I am able to program other boards using this ST-Link - a STM8 board. In this particular board, at the moment there is nothing else apart from the STM32F030. I can try to power it separately too. I will do that and update.
